# Visual Studio compiles some files every time (even when no changes are made)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, cuda

I've been developing an application on VS2008 and everything went very well. I made some alterations, on the name of the solution and projects, and that's about when I started going crazy with the following behavior:

- I clean my solution;
- Every file is recompiled (normal up to here);
- I make **no changes whatsoever** in **any** file and VS compile a set of files again;
- Still with no changes made, the same files get recompiled every time.

If somebody has an idea of might be going on, that would be fantastic. If not, what kind of tests can I do to investigate this further?

Thanks

EDIT:

- The language used is C++ with CUDA extensions;
- The files being compiled every time are .cu files

Comment: It may help if you mention which language you're using.  Also, have a read of some of the semi-related links, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486628/reason-why-a-vs-2008-project-is-being-rebuilt-each-time.

Comment: Just added some more relevant(?) information. What differs from my problem and the other posts is that even if I change absolutely nothing, those files are still compiled again.

Comment: I haven't used cuda, but it looks like it uses custom build events, you may want to check these to make sure they're still correct.  You could also try opening the VS project file in notepad (or similar) and checking to make sure that there aren't any references to the old names for the project.  It could be that some of your build targets are a bit confused.  Another alternative is to recreate the 'new' project files again from scratch, adding in all the source files etc (but obviously that's a bit of a pain)...

Comment: Don't ask me why, but making changes to those files and compiling them again solved the problem...

Answer (score 6):

Probably those file had had file modification date in the future, and after you saved them their date became in the past.